# SSIS Substring/Parse column string

Tags: ssis

In SSIS, how would you parse the values between the " " in this example:

KeyFieldForRecord:"ORD101300"}

So that the derived column value only returns: ORD101300 ?

I think the fact that the source wraps what I need in "" will make it challenging to use any of the SSIS string functions

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `REPLACE` in your derived column:

```
 REPLACE(KeyFieldForRecord, "\"", "")
```